# App opens anyways even though it was closed previously

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am working on an app and while testing on my phone a noticed something weird: if I close the app while the splash screen is running, when the time of the before mention activity is over, the app opens again, even if I am in another app. Why does this happen?

Comment: post ur code so we can fix it , it is because of background thread that open the activity

Answer (score 0):

Override the onDestroy Method in SplashActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //remove the handler or thread or etc... that is opening the another activity
        //call timer.cancel()
        //call timer.purge ()
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

So Your code will be now :

```
package com.example.arlet.storemaps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//duration of splash screen in miliseconds
long delay = 6000;
private Timer RunSplash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    RunSplash = new Timer();

    TimerTask ShowSplash = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //finishing splash screen
            finish();

            //starting main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    RunSplash.schedule(ShowSplash, delay);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    if(RunSplash != null){
    RunSplash.cancel();
    RunSplash.purge();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(RunSplash != null){
        RunSplash.cancel();
        RunSplash.purge();
    }
    super.onPause();
} 
}
```

Comment: hi, i'm sorry it took me a while, but I tried your answer and it didn't work

Comment: post ur splash screen class code so i can answer it correctly , I can't answer it 100% without knowing what is in there :D so I gave the case where most of people almost forget to implement

Comment: check out the comments I have written them for you, u have to call timer.cancel (); timer.purge () before super.OnDestroy () and make the timer private global variable so u can access it

Comment: okay, so I implemented what you told me, but when I run the app and the splash screen finished loading it says: unfortunately, app name has stopped.

Comment: don't apologize, but you should learn Java basics at least before moving to Android development, and always when u ask a question please include ur code in it so we can help better

Comment: ummm now the splash screen never ends

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.arlet.storemaps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//duration of splash screen in miliseconds
long delay = 6000;
private Timer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Timer RunSplash = new Timer();

    TimerTask ShowSplash = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //finishing splash screen
            finish();

            //starting main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    RunSplash.schedule(ShowSplash, delay);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Here's the code updated @Badran

Comment: and how are you expecting my solution to work and you haven't implemented it,I told you to remove all timers and handlers before super.onDestroy () and u r not removing anything

Comment: okay, I will, and sorry I am not experienced in android studio